# How can I integrate Laravel Notifications with my website?

Tags: php, database, laravel, notifications

I have recently completed the task of setting up database notifications with Laravel. I am now able to send notifications. What I want to do now, however, is: when I send a notification, I want an icon (such as a bell) to appear on my website, where users can hover over this icon and see the notification header, or click on it to read the full content. Is this possible?

Also, is there a way that I can get a database to see all notifications that I have sent? Perhaps using MySQL.

Comment: Is it possible?  Of course.  Your question is pretty broad and unclear.

Comment: I don't think its unclear. I am asking for specific instructions on how this can be implemented.

Comment: Well, you said you completed database notifications and ask a broad question about how to implement a front end for them, that isn't specific and doesn't have a clear solution.  Then you ask how you can get a database to see the notifications, which is a completely different question and conflicts with you saying you completed database notifications, so that's why it's unclear.  Stackoverflow isn't a discussion site, it's a Q&A, questions without clear solutions are discouraged.  I suggest you visit the help section to see how to improve your questions.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding this. I used Laravel to send Notifications, through the database channel (one of many options such as mail, slack, SMS). Now I want o see a database of all the notifications I have sent. I have already created the front end - just want to know how to get the notifications to show up there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's super easy get the latest notification and count .. Though the only differentiating factor here is how do you know there is a new notification from all your notifications. So I would suggest this design on your database.

**Database**

```
[id, name, latest]
```

Note: latest colunm is an integer type .eg. 0 or 1, where 0 is not latest and 1 is latest.

**Inserting a Notification**
So when you insert data save new notification in the db as latest e.g

```
$notification = new Notification();
$notification->name = 'whatever';
$notification->latest = 1; // important part
$notification->save()
```

**Retrieving latest notification and Displaying a Bell**

```
$latest_notification = Notification::where('latest', 1)->first(); // latest
//before responding to view - save notification as 0
$latest_notification->latest = 0;
$latest_notification->save();

if(latest_notification->isNotNull) {
return["latest" => latest_notification]
}else{
return["latest" => 0];
}
```

**Front End Displaying Bell**

```
<span id="notifier"></span>
```

**Javascript -- Jquery**
// if your response is not 0 then you have notification
// After post request to the server post or axios whatever you use

```
if(response.latest !== 0) {
$('#notifier').html('<i class="fas fa-bell"></i>' + '1')
} else {
$('#notifier').html('0')
}
```

Sorry have not had time to test this but this sure point you somewhere, all the best.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite useful. So I put the final block of code in the front end file for my website, and where should I put the other code?

Comment: The Other code is javascript, in a javascript file you are using for your website. The PHP code use it in laravel

Comment: I've actually written my website in Vue, but it will still work. What Laravel file do I put the PHP code in?

Comment: In your laravel Controller file where you are doing operations of adding data to the db

Comment: Ok, so I'll put the first two blocks of code into the Controller.php file.

Comment: How about the bell? Does that go into the front-end? Also, where in the controller file should I put the code? Sorry about all these questions! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

Yes, you can fetch the notification for every user like this:

**In controller that you want to pass the result of notification for every user**

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
   foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
   echo $notification->type;
}
```

For the second question you should add a value to `toArray` function like th
And you can count the notification and show the message on header on anywhere you want with helping Ajax call or by every refresh html page,

**In notification file**

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'sender_id' => $this->user->id,
    ];
}
```

After that when you want to fetch this data (query on notification table to find notifications that you send) you can use [JSON Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses)

I hope it will help you,

Comment: Thank you very much. Where should I put this code? Inside my test notification?

Comment: Which sample code you mean? the first or the second?

Comment: Well, for both.

Comment: Watch this tutorial it will help you to create notification in laravel. it will cover your first question. [Notification in Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tkq0H-McErE&t=205s)

Comment: I have edited my answer for your question : Where should I put this code?